# 406 Not Acceptable: Spring MVC + JSON

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

I know this question has been asked many times, although I tried what has been said but I still have this issue. 
I'm trying to generate a simple JSON response working. Right now I get 406 Not Acceptable error. Tomcat says "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers."
In tomcat/lib I have jackson jars. I'm using Spring 1.1.0 with Tomcat 7. 
I addedd the dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**CompaniesRestController.java**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Companies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Companies> listCompaniess() {
        return new java.util.ArrayList<Companies>(companiesService.loadCompaniess());
    }
```

I added this code snippet in my `applicationContext.xml`, as described in the : [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody):

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <util:list id="beanList">
        <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>
      </util:list>
    </property
</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter" 
       class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" 
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
  <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
</bean>
```

But in vain, none of all that worked.

I'd be thankfull for your suggestions.

PS: I used scaffolding to generate my CRUD application.

-Regards

Actually, when I edit my 
**CompaniesRestController.java**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Companies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String<Companies> listCompaniess() {
        return new java.util.ArrayList<Companies>(companiesService.loadCompaniess()).toString();
    }
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Companies", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")

    public @ResponseBody Object[] listCompaniess() {
        return new java.util.ArrayList<Companies>(companiesService.loadCompaniess()).toArray();

    }
```

I no longer have the 406error, I get an array containing the records I have in my database, but as an array, not a json...

I've tried to make use if JSONObject, but still have the same issue, I used scaffolding to create my spring mvc application, and then I convert it to a Maven project so as to add jackson libraries and dependencies, but when I cenvert it, all the project collapses and throws the following errors:

```
2015-07-15 17:32:31,299 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2015-07-15 17:32:31,314 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000427: Using deprecated org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookup strategy [hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class], use newer org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform strategy instead [hibernate.transaction.jta.platform]
2015-07-15 17:32:31,314 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000428: Encountered legacy TransactionManagerLookup specified; convert to newer org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform contract specified via hibernate.transaction.jta.platform setting
2015-07-15 17:32:31,314 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-07-15 17:32:31,361 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] Version - Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
2015-07-15 17:32:31,642 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
No properties path set - looking for transactions.properties in classpath...
transactions.properties not found - looking for jta.properties in classpath...
Using init file: /D:/Users/ielhazit/Workspaces/MyEclipse%202015%20CI/.metadata/.me_tcat7/webapps/chouette/WEB-INF/classes/jta.properties
juil. 15, 2015 5:32:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Infos: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'chouette Servlet'
2015-07-15 17:32:32,471 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] FrameworkServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1897)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:194)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.configureParameterNameProviderIfPossible(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:276)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:245)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 32 more
```

Any ideas
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The producible media types of the mapped request can also be configured by Spring's `@RequestMapping`.

Example : `@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")`

Comment: I've already tried that annotation but still have the same problem.

Comment: As per your updated question, you don't get that error now and you getting the data but not in JSON format. You can have that in JSON format with two ways : 1 - Return your own Model object and not Object[] 2- If you dont want to create a new Model object, make use of JSONObject.

Comment: The project I have is really huge, so I can't afford editting every class to return my own Model Object
*even the JSONObject doesn't help, still have the 406 error